# The Apex class 'ParkLocator' does not appear to be calling the SOAP endpoint

Tags: apex

I am getting error The Apex class 'ParkLocator' does not appear to be calling the SOAP endpoint.

Salesforce Trailhead requirement is
1.  Use WSDL2Apex to generate a class called 'ParkService' in public scope using this    https://th-apex-soap-service.herokuapp.com/assets/parks.xml WSDL  file.

2. Create a class called 'ParkLocator' that has a 'country'
   method that uses the 'ParkService' class and returns an array of
   available park names for a particular country passed to the web
   service. Possible country names that can be passed to the web
   service include Germany, India, Japan and United States.
3. Create a test class named ParkLocatorTest that uses a mock class called
   ParkServiceMock to mock the callout response.

---

```
public class ParkLocator {
            public static string[] country(String country) {
                parkService.parksImplPort park = new parkService.parksImplPort();
                return park.byCountry(country);
            }
}
```

---

**I have a parksServices class**

```
  //Generated by wsdl2apex
 public class parksServices {
        public class byCountryResponse {
            public String[] return_x;
            private String[] return_x_type_info = new String[]{'return','http://parks.services/',null,'0','-1','false'};
            private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://parks.services/','false','false'};
            private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'return_x'};
        }
        public class byCountry {
            public String arg0;
            private String[] arg0_type_info = new String[]{'arg0','http://parks.services/',null,'0','1','false'};
            private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://parks.services/','false','false'};
            private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'arg0'};
        }
        public class ParksImplPort {
            public String endpoint_x = 'https://th-apex-soap-service.herokuapp.com/service/parks';
            public Map<String,String> inputHttpHeaders_x;
            public Map<String,String> outputHttpHeaders_x;
            public String clientCertName_x;
            public String clientCert_x;
            public String clientCertPasswd_x;
            public Integer timeout_x;
            private String[] ns_map_type_info = new String[]{'http://parks.services/', 'parksServices'};
            public String[] byCountry(String arg0) {
                parksServices.byCountry request_x = new parksServices.byCountry();
                request_x.arg0 = arg0;
                parksServices.byCountryResponse response_x;
                Map<String, parksServices.byCountryResponse> response_map_x = new Map<String, parksServices.byCountryResponse>();
                response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
                WebServiceCallout.invoke(
                  this,
                  request_x,
                  response_map_x,
                  new String[]{endpoint_x,
                  '',
                  'http://parks.services/',
                  'byCountry',
                  'http://parks.services/',
                  'byCountryResponse',
                  'parksServices.byCountryResponse'}
                );
                response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
                return response_x.return_x;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I noticed that you have a "parksServices" class
This should be ParkService according to the Trailhead 
and to make this a valid call - new ParkService.ParksImplPort();
The class has a capital P!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your third line in **ParkLocator class** with

```
 parkService.ParksImplPort park = new parkService.ParksImplPort();
```

**ParksImplPort** is case sensitive here.

Answered [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000MIwfIAG)

Answer (score -1):

Based on my experience with this trailhead it looks like you're missing the remote site setting.

Did you add the remote site? https://th-apex-soap-service.herokuapp.com is the one for this trail.

Comment: if remote site setting is missing it throws following error "Unauthorized endpoint, please check Setup->Security->Remote site settings. endpoint = https://th-apex-soap-service.herokuapp.com/service/parks"

Comment: Yes, i've misread the question!